# Exception in Map Reduce job

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

i have created a map reduce job to fetch the number of employees of a location.
I am using hazelcast 3.6.3. Each employee has name and address.

I have added my code to following git repository.
https://github.com/adasari/hazelcast-demo

Exception :

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.DistinctValuesAggregation$SimpleEntry cannot be cast to com.hazelcast.query.impl.Extractable
>       at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.task.TrackableJobFuture.setResult(TrackableJobFuture.java:68)
>       at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.task.JobSupervisor.notifyRemoteException(JobSupervisor.java:156)
>       at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.operation.NotifyRemoteExceptionOperation.run(NotifyRemoteExceptionOperation.java:54)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:172)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:393)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processPacket(OperationThread.java:184)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:124)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:99)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.DistinctValuesAggregation$SimpleEntry cannot be cast to com.hazelcast.query.impl.Extractable
>       at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.readAttributeValue(AbstractPredicate.java:129)
>       at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.apply(AbstractPredicate.java:55)

can you point me the issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for or what you're trying to do (looking at the code) but your problem is here:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.DistinctValuesAggregation$SimpleEntry cannot be cast to com.hazelcast.query.impl.Extractable

So you have to implement the Extractable interface with your SimpleEntry class.

Comment: hi.. Thanks for reply.
SimpleEntry is extending QueryableEntry which is implementing Extractable. 

I am looking for output like Solr facets location of employee and number of employees from that location.

I will add more comments to code and push it to github.

Comment: Added more comments.

Comment: Seems the problem is 
>
 public int getFactoryId() {
  return AggregationsDataSerializerHook.F_ID;
 }

 public int getId() {
  return AggregationsDataSerializerHook.DISTINCT_VALUES_MAPPER;
 }

instead of IdentifiedDataSerializable, used DataSerializable. and it is working.  AggregationsDataSerializerHook.DISTINCT_VALUES_MAPPER is returning DistinctValuesAggregation mapper.

Comment: I will do more tests and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on MapReduce but below are my observation while looking/executing the code.

1. The place it is failing is a different `SimpleEntry` class, an inner class of `DistinctValuesAggregation` which doesn't implement `Extractable`.
2. There is already a defect in Hazelcast([#7398](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7398)) but it says closed in 3.6.1 so might as well follow up with them in Git hub.
3. I found that the code works well when you run the Cluster with just single node. So I suspect the above defect would be impacting the aggregation over multiple nodes.

   ```
   HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = buildCluster(1);
   ```

Comment: @Desai - Yes you are correct and it is failing in multinode only. In DistinctValesAggregation#SimpleEntry implementing Map.Entry, so it is failing. 
I looked at other class given in the bug and used similar SimpleEntry and it is still failing.

Comment: It's a defect in Hazelcast. I even tried with 3.7-EA and there its failing for some other ClassCast as it's expecting the key to be Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Following actions resolved the issue -
1. DistinctMapper implements DataSerializable
2. SimpleEntry extends QueryableEntry